# What is the rationale behind the constant return value for DOS int 21 / AH=9? (print string interrupt)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I was looking at the specifications for DOS `int 21h` interrupts here [http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html)

I don't know much about assembly, but it seems like the AL register is the standard to store return values from an interrupt. For instance, service 01h (read character) stores the character read there. And service 02h (write character to stdout) stores the last character output there.

But when it comes to AH=09h (write string to stdout) the return value is ALWAYS 24h. Why is that?

First I thought that SOME value has to be set for some technical reason, but that does not seem to be the case. There are lots of DOS services that don't specify a return value at all. And some store the return value in other registers, such as 2Ch (get system time) which instead stores the result in CH, CL, DH and DL registers instead of AL.

So why does interrupt service AH=09h store a value in AL? And why 24h?

Comment: It is a bit strange and seems "incidental" to me.... i.e., maybe that's what happens to always be in AL when it does what it does and then returns, so that's what they say. But then, why say it at all in that case? Interesting question. This may end up being closed as being opinion-based unless someone answers based upon knowing the details of the implementation of the interrupt.

Comment: @lurker Yeah, the good old "opinion based" :) That is so overused. And especially since this question is not opinion based whatsoever. It has a clear answer. Maybe there's no one who knows the answer, but that's a completely different thing.

Comment: [Another source says](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm) _"AL = 24h (the '$' terminating the string, despite official docs which state that nothing is returned)"_

Comment: @Jester Oh, but then it really makes sense. It's the last character in the string, which always is the $-terminator

Comment: @Jester Should I write an answer or do you want the honor?

Comment: It does make sense but sounds accidental. Go ahead and write an answer if you feel like it :)

Comment: Nitpick: It is not "interrupt 09h" (that's something else, specifically the IRQ #1 handler) but it is "interrupt 21h service 09h".

Comment: @ecm Nice. Added it to the answer

Comment: Doh! Yeah, the `$`. I didn't bother looking up the ASCII representation of 24h. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Just for a few more details:

You can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/04a3d20ff411409ab98474892b2bb1713bde0f7f/v1.25/source/MSDOS.ASM#L3172) the source code for this system call in MS-DOS v1.25:

```
PRTBUF: ;System call 9
        MOV     SI,DX
OUTSTR:
        LODSB
        CMP     AL,"$"
        JZ      RET20
        CALL    OUT
        JMP     SHORT OUTSTR
```

It uses the `LODSB` instruction in a loop to load bytes from the string, compare them against `$`, and write them out.  Since `LODSB` is hard-wired to load into `AL`, and the loop terminates when `$` is seen, that's what's left in `AL`.

The DOS API specified that AX need not be preserved by system calls (see [MS-DOS Programmer's Reference Manual](https://www.pcjs.org/documents/books/mspl13/msdos/dosref40/), 1.10.4, "Treatment of Registers"), and the return value from service 09h is just described as "None".  So there is no documented guarantee as to what AL should contain on exit; its contents are simply unspecified.  Other versions of DOS may have behaved differently, so you obviously should not rely on such behavior.

Answer (score 3):

@Jester did a very good observation. 24h is the ascii code for $, and the service 09h is expecting a $-terminated string. Compare to the service 02h that prints the last character to the output, and this character ends up in AL. And now we're talking about a function that prints a $-terminated string, and leaves $ in the AL register.

This hypothesis would also explain why the official documentation doesn't specify any return value for that interrupt. It's not a part of the specification, but just a result of the inner workings.

So while I (or Jester) cannot say for certain that there is no thought behind this, this explanation makes a lot of sense.

And as @ecm pointed out. It's not "interrupt 09h". It's "interrupt 21h service 09h".

Comment: The right place to address the "not interrupt 9" is in an edit to the question (which I just did before seeing ecm's comment :P), not in an answer.  That's the kind of comment that is actually suggesting an improvement to the post, not answering.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, you're right. I thought about it, but I wanted to stand for my mistakes, but of course you're right.