# What is the rationale behind $ terminated strings?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I was revisiting [one of my old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66334295/6699433) which involved $ terminated strings. That was the way to do it with ms-dos syscalls.

But what was the reason for choosing $ to terminate strings? The zero character makes much more sense. Why did they choose a printable character?

Comment: *"Why did they choose a printable character?"* - I'd guess that "printable" is the keyword here, since in MS-DOS era you would have to do a lot of manual low-level debugging, and a printable character is easy to recognize.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Oh, nice there

Comment: See this [Why did DOS use dollar-terminated strings? - retrocomputing stackexchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7638/why-did-dos-use-dollar-terminated-strings)

Comment: I'm actually not sure what to do when there's a duplicate on another SE site

Comment: I think in this case, it is basically a retrocomputing question, so could get migrated there.  And then closed as a duplicate, so instead you might as well delete this.  And then link the retrocomputing Q&A from your answer on [What is the rationale behind the constant return value for DOS int 21 / AH=9? (print string interrupt)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66334295) - so there will still be a link from somewhere on Stack Overflow to that retrocomputing Q&A, in case that matters for people searching just this site.

Comment: In general, there isn't a good way to handle cross-site duplicates on stack-exchange, for cases where the question could be on-topic on both sites.